# Web 8 Content Manager Explorer Interface Issues

Tags: installation, web8

We have just installed SDL Web 8 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server with SQL Server 2012 SP2 for the database. We ran into a few issues during the installation (one was around the use of host name headers) and ended up having to start over but eventually got it installed.

However, when viewing the Content Manager Explorer (regardless of browser used) we do not see the interface as it should look based upon screenshots we've seen. Instead the main part of the interface appears to be missing some style sheets (though we don't see any errors in the network inspector or console).

Here is a screen shot.
[image: Main Content Manager Explorer Screen - Web 8]

We are not able to do anything that you can normally do in the CME. We're about to dump the databases and start from scratch, but wondered if anyone else has seen this. Seems like something simple is missing, but there are no errors in the logs and I would expect things to function after a fresh install (unless we missed some steps).

Update per comments: We have tried this in IE, Chrome and Firefox (and have configured the browsers per the instructions).

While troubleshooting, we found the following error buried within one of the individual XHR requests for the Welcome_v8.1.0.194.5_.aspx?mode=css resource.

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CssPathCorrector.Process(String fileContents, String filePath)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedCssFile.PreprocessContents(String contents, Boolean debug)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedFile.get_Contents()
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedFile.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, CachedResourceType resourceType, List\`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedCssGroup.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, CachedResourceType resourceType, List\`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedCssGroup.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, CachedResourceType resourceType, List\`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedCssGroup.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, CachedResourceType resourceType, List\`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedCssGroup.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, CachedResourceType resourceType, List\`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedCssPageResources.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, CachedResourceType resourceType, List\`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Common.HttpUtilities.OutputWithHTTPCacheHeaders(ICachedResource resource, CachedResourceType resourceType, Nullable\`1 cacheDuration)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

That doesn't show up in the console log and we didn't see it in the Tridion event log - it is contained within the response for this particular request. We found it using the Chrome Developer Tools network inspector.

We observed the same thing for some other resources that have ?mode=css specified.

Comment: I'd recommend contacting SDL support - i'm sure they'll help you get fixed up

Comment: Agree with @johnwinter - please contact Customer Support, as we want to be able to figure out why this happens - and be able to prevent it in the future, of course. Have you tried re-running the installer and doing a repair?

Comment: @NunoLinhares We had already opened a ticket with Customer Support, but wanted to bring this to the community in case any one else had seen it and found a solution. I'll update the post to include some additional information we have found.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check `\SDL Web\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config` and see if the Repair added a duplicate of one of the `<editor>` sections.
If yes, remove the duplicated one.

Comment: Thank you, @Mr.T! This was exactly the problem. Now we have a working Web 8 UI.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced exactly same issue twice (while playing on my local VM) - One while I upgrade a Tridion 2013 SP1 instance and try to Repair (for a missing piece) and again when I try to add-on new feature in a fresh install.

After trying a lots of tries, re-repairing etc., the only resolution comes to me as - Uninstall CM completely (from control panel), reboot the server and Re-install the installer with all required features for CM

Comment: We seem unable to reproduce this... any info you guys can gather is welcome

Answer (score 2):

we have faced same issue ,we didn't solved issue after trying a lots of tries,re-repairing.
we have found below tag multiple times in system.config file

      C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\Compatibility.7_1.CME\
      Configuration\CME.config
      Compatibility.7_1.CME
     
we have removed duplicated tags and it is working fine post clear browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue and I believe it could because of Repair step. In my case I have removed duplicate node of `<editor name="Compatibility.7_1.CME">` which cause this issue.